# Is the Traffic between sidecar and main process encrypted in istio?

Tags: security, microservices, istio

I know that istio supports mTLS for inter-service communication done through istio proxy but I couldn't find any documentation on their official site explaining the state of traffic between istio proxy container & main container itself in a pod ? (assuming it's a kubernetes managed cluster)

Is the traffic encrypted between proxy and main containers ? If it's not by default, is there any config or plugin out there that can enable this behaviour ?

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traffic between the application and the sidecar proxy is not encrypted. It is mentioned, for example, [here](https://istio.io/docs/examples/advanced-gateways/egress-tls-origination/#additional-security-considerations).