# TLS security needed between sidecar and main container inside pod

Tags: security, kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-pod, sidecar

I am working on solution wherein I have one sidecar alongwith main container in one pod , sidecar is working as a proxy for traffic going out of the pod.
Do I need any kind of encryption/TLS security between sidecar and main container if yes then how can I achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your security requirements. Traffic between the main container and Istio sidecar [is not encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443582/is-the-traffic-between-sidecar-and-main-process-encrypted-in-istio). I guess if you are, for example, getting started with Istio or a similar solution and don't know if this is required, it is very likely you don't need that, though.